# Flutter open url according to image clicked

Tags: android, html, ios, flutter, webview

I need to do sort of like 'hyperlink' a `url` to an `image`/`List()`. Currently I am making a `UI` and upon clicking an `image` it will open a specific `url`. And also i have made a `search list` and i want to achieve upon clicking the `topic` it will open the respective `url`. For example, clicking imageA will open `https://example.com/data1.html` and imageD `https://example.com/data4.html`, topicA will open `https://example.com/data1.html` and topicD `https://example.com/data4.html`. Should I use  `url_launcher` or `WebView` to show the html page? Thank you.

**CODE**

```
...

  child:Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200.0 ,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                       return buildCalc(data[index],context);
                      },
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      ),
                      )
...
```

using buildCalc function to insert images

```
Widget buildCalc(Data data,context){
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0, right:10.0, top:10.0),
    child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>Opticsdata(data: data,)),);
        },
...
                    Hero(
                        tag: data.id,
                        child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage(data.image),
                        )
                 children: [
                        Text(
                          data.id,
                          ),
 ...
```

```
...

var url ="https://example.com/data1.html";
   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("url:" + url);
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        home: Scaffold(
    body: WebView(
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,  
          initialUrl: url,    
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {   
            controller = webViewController;
          }),
  

  }
}
```

```
 class Data{
  String image;
  String id;
  Data({this.id,this.image});
}
List<Data> data = [
  Data(id: '01',image: 'img/O1-resize.png'),
  Data(id: '02',image: 'img/O2-resize.png'),
  Data(id: '03',image: 'img/O3-resize.png'),
  Data(id: '04',image: 'img/O4-resize.png'),
  Data(id: '05',image: 'img/O5-resize.png')
];
```

Data file

**EDIT**

Previous coding was very messy and I have done a simpler version of it. Below is the code if anyone needs it.

```
...
 children: ListTile.divideTiles
                (
                  context: context,
                  tiles: 
                  [
                  ListTile
                  (
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                       radius: 50,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage("img/I1-resize.png"), // no matter how big it is, it won't overflow
                    ),
                    title: Text("Angular resolution calculator"),
                     onTap: (){
                    _launch('https://example.com/data1.html');
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile
                  (
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                       radius: 50,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage("img/I2-resize.png"), // no matter how big it is, it won't overflow
                    ),
                    title: Text("Diffraction limit calculator"),
                     onTap: (){
                    _launch('https://example.com/data2.html');
                    },
                  ),
                  
                ]
                ).toList(),
...
```

This will create a `Listview` with image and `onTap` will launch the `url` via `url_launcher`.

```
Future<void> _launch(String url) async{
  
  
    if (await canLaunch(url)) { 
      
      await launch(url, forceSafariVC: true, forceWebView: true , enableJavaScript: true,); 
      
    } else { 
      throw 'Could not launch $url'; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please shorten your code to a minimal code; it is so unreadable that nobody could find where in the code the actual question is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try url [url_launcher 5.7.10](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) for this,

```
  new Center(
          child: new InkWell(
              child: new Text('Medium Article', style: TextStyle(
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
              ),
              ),
              onTap: () => launch('https://shirsh94.medium.com/android-11-top-new-11-features-for-android-a83c3b0fe4fe')
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Url_package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) from pub.dev

```
Center(
      child: new InkWell(
          child: new Text('Open Image', style: TextStyle(
            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
          ),
          ),
          onTap: () => launch('www.google.com')
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use url launch package as it was previously mentioned, however, as it is a async do not forget check is your link ready or not. (It's also in package docs).

For example create launch class:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class Launch {
  static void launchUrl(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

then you can call it wherever you want to:

```
Center(
      child: new InkWell(
          child: new Text('Open Image', style: TextStyle(
            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
          ),
          ),
          onTap: () => Launch.launchUrl(url)
      ),
    ),
```